# ASP.NET menu item change navigate url in codebehind

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS2010/C#, how can I change ASP.NET menu item navigate URL property in code behind? it seems that ASP:MENU items don't have any ID, so how can I access them in codebehind?

thanks

Comment: on which event you have to do this

Comment: what do you mean exactly by event? I just want to change ASP:MENUITEM navigate url in codebehind, of course I'v seen menu item onclick event but I think it's better to change navigate url, is it possible at all? can I set ID and runat=server for menu items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Menu1.Items[0].NavigateUrl = "http:stackoverflow.com";
```

menu is a  collection of items so you can use indexing for access any particular item in menu